# Correctly sizing nested ribbongroups using controlsizedefinitions

Tags: layout, custom-controls, ribbon

I'm extending the RibbonGroup and removing the padding/margins so they can be nested without getting ugly (as long as the header is unset or null); however, I'm having difficulty determining the correct ControlSizeDefinition objects to add to the GroupSizeDefinitions that I'm adding to the group for sizing information.

My approach is as follows:
If an Item in the RibbonGroup is a RibbonGroup, then add a ControlSizeDefinition with the Width set to the width that I'd like the control to be after sizing.  To determine the width I request the desired size of the control.  Nice, but I've only got one size.  Nearest I can tell, the best way to do this would be to set the current GroupSizeDefinition.  How can I do that, or if this is the wrong way to go about this, what is the correct way?

edit:
Using C# in VS2012.

edit: Here's code that pretty much illustrates the issue.  Try it with and without the group size definitions to see the behavior.

```
<RibbonTab Header="Test">
    <RibbonGroup Header="Nestable">
        <RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions>
            <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
                <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="True" IsCollapsed="False"/>
                <RibbonControlSizeDefinition Width="138"/>
                <RibbonControlSizeDefinition Width="148"/>
            </RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
            <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
                <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="False" IsCollapsed="False"/>
                <RibbonControlSizeDefinition Width="138"/>
                <RibbonControlSizeDefinition Width="148"/>
            </RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
            <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
                <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="False" IsCollapsed="False"/>
                <RibbonControlSizeDefinition Width="78"/>
                <RibbonControlSizeDefinition Width="148"/>
            </RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
        </RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions>
        <RibbonButton Label="Button" SmallImageSource="16x16.png" LargeImageSource="32x32.png"/>
        <RibbonGroup>
            <RibbonButton Label="Button" SmallImageSource="16x16.png"/>
            <RibbonButton Label="Button" SmallImageSource="16x16.png"/>
            <RibbonButton Label="Button" SmallImageSource="16x16.png"/>
            <RibbonButton Label="Button" SmallImageSource="16x16.png"/>
        </RibbonGroup>
        <RibbonGroup>
            <RibbonButton Label="Button" SmallImageSource="16x16.png" LargeImageSource="32x32.png"/>
            <RibbonButton Label="Button" SmallImageSource="16x16.png" LargeImageSource="32x32.png"/>
            <RibbonButton Label="Button" SmallImageSource="16x16.png" LargeImageSource="32x32.png"/>
        </RibbonGroup>
    </RibbonGroup>
</RibbonTab>
```

Comment: Hi, you haven't mentioned what language you are using. If you provide us with some code examples of where you're stuck, we'll be more likely to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone else is looking for the answer to this; however, I did come up with one.  Unfortunately it isn't a simple fix.  Each nested ribbon group has to measure its individual controls and essentially do an Arrange (without actually doing the layout) pass to determine the sizes it should have for the various group size definitions.  Then during your actual arrange pass, you've got to manually set the control size definitions for your children.